# Не выходит из цикла while C#

Tags: c#, while

Код до этого работал, перестал после обновления на VS 2019.

Переменная:

```
public int sp_packetAvailable = 0;      // Флаг завершения приема пакета
```

Кусок зависающего кода:

```
while (sp_packetAvailable == 0)
{                                       
}
```

Стоит кнопка, которая открывает ком порт и принимает данные, если данные верные, ставится флаг:

> sp_packetAvailable == 1

После этого бесконечный цикл прерывался и продолжалось выполнение кода. Но увы, данные получаю, флаг на 1 ставится, а цикл так и крутит. Повторюсь, перестало работать после перехода с 2017 на 2019.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вы уверены, что он доходит до этого места? На скрине не видно, что сработала точка в этом месте.

Comment: Именно, она на этом месте и останавливается. У меня на этой точке стоит brakepoint. Я, к сожалению, не выделил его в скриншоте.

Comment: Сюда по описанию переменная используется в двух потоках. Если это так то [здесь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_ABA) описано по чему так происходит. Использовать для так целей обычную целочисленную перемененную, не очень хорошо. Лучше воспользоваться [AutoResetEvent](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.autoresetevent?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

AlexF прав, надо было использовать:

> public volatile int sp_packetAvailable = 0;